# How do I make a Windows batch script completely silent?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

There has been variants of this question asked for generations, but despite writing some quite complicated Windows scripts, I can't seem to find out how to make them actually silent.

The following is an excerpt from one of my current scripts:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET scriptDirectory=%~dp0
COPY %scriptDirectory%test.bat %scriptDirectory%test2.bat
FOR /F %%f IN ('dir /B "%scriptDirectory%*.noext"') DO (
del "%scriptDirectory%%%f"
)
ECHO
```

The result of this is:

```
C:\Temp> test.bat
        1 file(s) copied.
File Not Found
Echo is off.

C:\Temp>
```

Whereas the "1 file(s) copied." is just annoying, the "File Not Found" makes the user think that something has gone wrong (which it hasn't - no files is fine).

Comment: If you ended up using different solution than those given please add your own answer and accept it. Don't add the solution to the question itself.

Comment: I've actually managed to remove the second "File Not Found" output by prefixing it with an if-condition:  IF EXIST "%scriptDirectory%*.noext" FOR /F %%f IN ('dir /B "%scriptDirectory%*.noext"') DO (...  This originally didn't work because I had tried to use IF <condition> DO().

Comment: I have changed the title to reflect @bobstein-visibone's [rather harsh, IMHO] comment.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

To suppress output, use redirection to `NUL`.

There are two kinds of output that console commands use:

- standard output, or `stdout`,
- standard error, or `stderr`.

Of the two, `stdout` is used more often, both by internal commands, like `copy`, and by console utilities, or *external* commands, like `find` and others, as well as by third-party console programs.

`>NUL` suppresses the standard output and works fine e.g. for suppressing the `1 file(s) copied.` message of the `copy` command. An alternative syntax is `1>NUL`. So,

```
COPY file1 file2 >NUL
```

or

```
COPY file1 file2 1>NUL
```

or

```
>NUL COPY file1 file2
```

or

```
1>NUL COPY file1 file2
```

suppresses all of `COPY`'s standard output.

To suppress error messages, which are typically printed to `stderr`, use `2>NUL` instead. So, to suppress a `File Not Found` message that `DEL` prints when, well, the specified file is not found, just add `2>NUL` either at the beginning or at the end of the command line:

```
DEL file 2>NUL
```

or

```
2>NUL DEL file
```

Although sometimes it may be a better idea to actually verify whether the file exists before trying to delete it, like you are doing in your own solution. Note, however, that you don't need to delete the files one by one, using a loop. You can use a single command to delete the lot:

```
IF EXIST "%scriptDirectory%*.noext" DEL "%scriptDirectory%*.noext"
```

Comment: Thanks, @AndriyM - my actual script does more than just delete the file, but I stripped it down for the question.  If I use 1>NUL, does that mean the error messages will still get shown?  That would be an improvement.

Comment: @MikeSadler: Yes, `1>NUL` suppresses only standard output. Error output will still be shown. When you need to suppress *all* the output for a command, use both `1>NUL` and `2>NUL` with it.

Comment: that's perfect - I'm happy for the user to see the error messages, if there are any.

Comment: `copy` does not write error messages to stderr but also to stdout. `copy ... >nul` will hide normal and error output. `xcopy` does it right though, so that may be an option. (Also set the `xcopy /q` option to get rid of the file names copied.)

Comment: It should be `copy /y ...`

Answer (score 15):

If you want that all normal output of your Batch script be silent (like in your example), the easiest way to do that is to run the Batch file with a redirection:

```
C:\Temp> test.bat >nul
```

This method does not require to modify a single line in the script and it still show error messages in the screen. To supress *all* the output, including error messages:

```
C:\Temp> test.bat >nul 2>&1
```

If your script have lines that produce output you want to appear in screen, perhaps will be simpler to add redirection to *those* lineas instead of all the lines you want to keep silent:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET scriptDirectory=%~dp0
COPY %scriptDirectory%test.bat %scriptDirectory%test2.bat
FOR /F %%f IN ('dir /B "%scriptDirectory%*.noext"') DO (
del "%scriptDirectory%%%f"
)
ECHO
REM Next line DO appear in the screen
ECHO Script completed >con
```

Antonio

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect stdout to `nul` to hide it.

```
COPY %scriptDirectory%test.bat %scriptDirectory%test2.bat >nul
```

Just add `>nul` to the commands you want to hide the output from.

[Here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) you can see all the different ways of redirecting the std streams.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `>NUL` at the end of the lines producing the messages.

For example,

`COPY %scriptDirectory%test.bat %scriptDirectory%test2.bat >NUL`

Answer (score 3):

Copies a directory named **html** & all its contents to a destination directory in silent mode. 
If the destination directory is not present it will still create it.

```
@echo off
TITLE Copy Folder with Contents

set SOURCE=C:\labs
set DESTINATION=C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\html

xcopy %SOURCE%\html\* %DESTINATION%\* /s /e /i /Y >NUL
```

---

1. /S           Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
2. /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty 
   ones. Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.
3. /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one
   file, assumes that destination must be a directory.
4. /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite
   an
                     existing destination file.