# Hide command output displaying in command console while running batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I created a batch file like given below , but this is not getting hidden in command prompt **evev** though echo off is used.

I doesn't want **csv** file or any other file to display in command prompt.
it is also showing warning using password in command prompt is insecure,
please help me.

this batch file when run in command prompt produces **W P.xls** as output file

```
@echo off
    echo %1 
    echo SET @bdate := "%1"; > a.sql
    copy /b a.sql + bdate.sql out.sql
    mysql --user="root" --database="abc" --password="123" < "D:\New   Folder\out.sql"
    java -jar csvtoxls.jar
    del out.sql
    del ws.csv
    rename "W P.xls" "W P"%1".xls"
```

jar file
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class csv2 {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allRowAndColData = null;
        ArrayList<String> oneRowData = null;
        String fName = "C:\\New folder\\ws.csv";
        String currentLine;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fName);
        DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
        int i = 0;
        allRowAndColData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        while ((currentLine=myInput.readLine()) != null) {
            oneRowData = new ArrayList<String>();
            String oneRowArray[] = currentLine.split(";");
            for (int j = 0; j < oneRowArray.length; j++) {
                oneRowData.add(oneRowArray[j]);
            }
            allRowAndColData.add(oneRowData);
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }

     try {
         HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
         HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
         for (int i1 = 0; i1 < allRowAndColData.size(); i1++) {
           ArrayList<?> ardata = (ArrayList<?>) allRowAndColData.get(i1);
           HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0 + i1);
           for (int k = 0; k < ardata.size(); k++) {
                System.out.print(ardata.get(k));
                HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) k);
                cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(k).toString());
           }
           System.out.println();
         }
       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream("C:\\New folder\\W P.xls");
       workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
       fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with java here?

Comment: no problem with java or jar file am getting out put but                                  mysql --user="root" --database="abc" --password="123" < "D:\New   Folder\out.sql"   is getting warning using password in command prompt is insecue

Comment: can you put your code please?

Comment: please tell me how to hide responses of below lines in command prompte     cho SET @bdate := "%1"; > a.sql
    copy /b a.sql + bdate.sql out.sql
    mysql --user="root" --database="abc" --password="123" < "D:\New   Folder\out.sql"

Comment: maybe the way that you are using in java make this problem, so just put your code i hope you get my point :)

Comment: GOT IT USE **mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --silent --force -b 2> nul** OR
**'mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --silent --force -b --tee=nul'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add @ sign for commands you want to hide.

Also add > nul in front of command if you don't want show output.

Comment: how to hide this line please help->mysql --user="root" --database="abc" --password="123" < "D:\New   Folder\out.sql"

Comment: Try as: @mysql --user="root" --database="abc" --password="123" < "D:\New   Folder\out.sql"

Comment: The `@echo off` at the top of the script adds an implied `@` to all lines, so that's unnecessary. The `>nul` should work, though.

Comment: Try as: @mysql --user="root" --database="abc" --password="123" < "D:\New Folder\out.sql" 1>NUL

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686330/how-do-i-make-a-dos-script-completely-silent

Comment: GOT IT USE **mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --silent --force -b 2> nul** OR
**'mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --silent --force -b --tee=nul'**